# Превышении размеров таблицы в БД

Tags: база-данных, postgresql

*Это теоретический вопрос, не имеющий отношения к конкретной БД.*

Для понимания как лучше реализовать архитектуру БД интересует: как быть при разрастании БД?
Если таблица превысит максимальный размер, нужно создавать копию таблицы? Или как это вообще работает?

**UPD.** БД `PostgreSQL`.

Comment: В каждой конкретной БД, этот вопрос решается по своему. Отвечать абстрактно не имеет смысла.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, дополнил.

Comment: Я специализируюсь в Oracle и Microsoft SQL. Ждем спецов по PostgreSQL.

Comment: У таблицы в современных БД практически нет максимального размера, она может занять весь диск, значит возьмите диск по больше, если все данные нужны. Либо удаляйте старые данные (и оставляйте например какие то их суммы, если они нужны). Еще могут кончиться ID, если есть подозрение что такое может произойти возьмите под ID поле bigint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Несмотря на то, что PostgreSQL делается во многом с оглядкой на Oracle и наследует многие механизмы из Oracle - в частности, концепцию Tablespaces, механизмы физического контроля занимаемого tablespace пространства в PostgreSQL отсутствуют. Отчасти это хорошо, потому что у всех Oracle-истов обычно есть админ на параше, который обязан следить за размером tablespaces и время от времени увеличивать их, естественно он на это забивает и периодически потом в организации раздаётся истошный вой, в результате которого админ получает заслуженный пистон - мог бы и мониторинг настроить что ли, если уж daily check делать в лом... PostgreSQL не может себе позволить требовать от своих пользователей выделять должность админа на параше, поэтому такие дурацкие ситуации исключены - база данных занимает столько места, сколько ей необходимо, и сколько может выделить операционная система и физический носитель. 
Есть в этом конечно и минусы - шутники могут найти уязвимости REST API и поставить скрипт записывать что-нибудь в вашу базу данных, она будет расти до тех пор пока не блокирует операционную систему и сайт, если за базой нет оперативного контроля.

Создавая Tablespaces вы можете гибко разделять хранение индексов и данных на различных физических носителях, в частности можно заранее продумать ограничения по размеру данных и индексов, создать средствами операционной системы тома на физическом носителе, а еще лучше использовать отдельные физические носители (только для данных и только для индексов) - и наслаждаться, следить только время от времени не пора ли заменить используемые носители на более объемные/быстрые.

З.Ы. Если очень-очень надо, физический размер database / tablespace / table можно контролировать при помощи триггеров при вставке данных - [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18202823/database-space-quotas-with-hibernate-and-postgresql-limit-database-megabytes-us) люди обсуждают подобное. Я бы так конечно не делал, важно обеспечить механизмы контроля чтобы в вашу БД попадала только полезная информация, а раз уж она полезная - физического пространства для ее хранения не должно быть жалко..

З.Ы.2. Лимит на размер таблицы в PostgreSQL - 32Tb по моему (может 64 даж, не помню), а лимиты на размер базы данных и tablespaces отсутствуют. Достигнуть такого размера конечно можно... но практических невозможно - еще задолго до этого, максимум на половине этого лимита, пользователи вас заставят перейти на Oracle и пройти их курсы администрирования ;-)